# Is nested DataSets possible in SSRS 2005?

Tags: reporting-services

Is it possible to have an outer  table  mapped to a dataset and use another table inside the outer table which maps to a second dataset,where the second dataset should take the feild value
from the first dataset(as parameter) to pull data?

Please comment

Thanks in advance,
San

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with a subreport. Pass in a parameter to use as a filter. If you're using a filter rather than a query parameter, it should be able to use the same Intermediate Report (ie, RDL + Data) for each subreport, thereby achieving your goal.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible.  Reporting Services doesn't support multiple datasets.  You'll need to get creative with your SQL to create a single dataset of all data.